# Defining recursive data types with tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble defining a new data type in Haskell.

I'm trying to create a data type `NumPair` that will be a tuple containing either two integers, or an integer and another `NumPair`.

So for instance, `(2, 2), (0, 5), (1, (2, 3)) and (0, (4, (3, 121)))` should all be valid `NumPairs`.

This is the code I've written to try to do this:

```
data NumPair = (Int, Int) | (Int, NumPair) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't work and what I should do instead, please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add constructor names for each alternative:

```
data NumPair = Pair (Int, Int) | More (Int, NumPair) deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Those constructor names are what let you pattern match on the data type like so:

```
f :: NumPair -> A
f (Pair (x, y )) = ...
f (More (x, np)) = ...
```

You can then build a value using the constructors to (which is why they are called constructors):

```
myNumPair :: NumPair
myNumPair = More (1, More (2, Pair (3, 4)))
```

There are two other ways you can improve your type.  Haskell constructors have built-in support for multiple fields, so rather than using a tuple you can just list the values directly in the constructor like this:

```
data NumPair = Pair Int Int | More Int NumPair deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Another way you can improve upon it is to recognize that you've just written the type for a non-empty list.  The best implementation for non-empty lists resides in `Data.List.NonEmpty` of the `semigroups` package, which you can [find here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/semigroups/0.8.4.1/doc/html/Data-List-NonEmpty.html).

Then your type just becomes:

```
type NumPair = NonEmpty Int
```

... and you get a bunch of function on non-empty lists for free from that module.

**Edit**: n.m. brought to my attention that what you probably wanted was:

```
data NumPair = Pair (Int, Int) | More ((Int, Int), NumPair)
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
type NumPair = NonEmpty (Int, Int)
```

The difference is that this latter one lets you append pairs of integers, where as the previous one that followed your question's type only lets you append integers.

Comment: This is rather a non-empty list of Int pairs.

Comment: @n.m. That would only be true if the `More` constructor had the shape `More ((Int, Int), NumPair)`.  I did make a mistake, though, as his type is actually non-empty in the sense that it guarantees two elements, not just one, so I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @n.m. Actually, I think you are right and what he wanted was actually a list of pairs of integers, otherwise the name `NumPair` wouldn't make sense, so I listed both solutions.

Comment: @n.m. Right, but I think he may have wanted it to append a pair of integers instead.

Answer (score 5):

What you desire is a "true union" type, which is not present in Haskell. Haskell provides only *tagged* unions, where the programmer must attach additional information to all data. There are tradeoffs to using true unions vs tagged unions; I won't try to sell you one way or the other on that. However, you *can* define a type exactly as desired by using a language that provides true union types, such as Typed Racket.

```
#lang typed/racket

(define-type Num-Pair
  (Rec R
    (U (Pair Integer Integer)
       (Pair Integer R))))

(: foo Num-Pair)
(define foo '(0 . (4 . (3 . 121))))
```